# Перезагрузка сервера без SSH

Tags: сервер, ssh, django

На сервер нет доступа по SSH. На нем расположен сайт на python(django), mysql, Apache, mod_python, mod_wsgi. Доступ дан только к Django админке, MySQL через phpMySdmin, и на сервер через FTP.

Однако если я изменю код Django приложений, то мне понадобиться перезагрузить сервер, дабы вступили в силу изменения. Как это делать если SSH доступа нет?

Comment: пальцем на ресет?))

Comment: Едете в дата-центр, наживаете reset -> profit :DDD

Comment: По сабжу есть предложения? Флудить в флудилку...

Comment: По сабжу - в тех поддержку пишите а не на форум

Comment: Django, mod_wsgi, python: OSQA на сервере стоит?

Comment: @AlexWindHope это по вашему по сабжу? Если бы можно было у хостера взять SSH доступ давно бы это сделал. Проблема именно в том что не будет SSH доступа, вот и спрашиваю возможно ли без него! @niki-timofe не знаю при чем тут OSQA, но нет, на сколько я знаю не стоит.

Comment: Конечно да.

Тогда вопрос выглядит так - возможно ли не имея доступа к банковскому счету снять с него деньги. Ответ для вас не очевиден?

Comment: @AlexWindHope Я понял стиль ваших ответов, спасибо за флуд, жаль модеры спят. И все же если кто сталкивался с подобным, ответьте по теме.

Comment: А где вы тут увидели ответ? Это комментарии, которые как-бы намекают вам на то, что этого сделать невозможно. Доступ к сайту, бд, ftp и root доступ к ОС немного разные вещи, не находите?..

Comment: Ниже предложение с cron, без root доступа, сработало если бы доступ был. Одну консоль нашел, которая прописывается в Apache и управляет сервером как в ssh работаешь. Не кажется вам что ваши коменты созревают из-за незнания темы, и подобное можно просто не писать, а искать вопросы на которые вы все же знаете ответ, и можете помочь людям. Тут ответ не очевиден, как и многое в программировании, если вы не можете это одним способом сделать, это не факт что никто не может другим это сделать. Помогайте людям, а не разводите троллинг. На этом форуме он совершенно не нужен.

Comment: @trek, c удовольствием плюсую за такой комментарий.

По делу. Идея состоит в том, что надо забить весь своп (обычно лимитов на память процесса нет). После этого админ будет вынужден перезагрузить сервак. 

На Си техника такого безобразия - это много fork() + calloc() (именно calloc или memset()...), чтобы реально модифицировать страницы. fork-и понятно, чтобы действительно много гигов памяти взять и (заодно) убегать (только сразу еще setsid() - уходите от kill на группу).

И еще. Вы уверены, что *такой хостер* Вам **нужен**  ?

Answer (score 2):

Первое, что в голову пришло - скрипт, который по наличию файла-флага (в `/tmp` или еще где) перезапускает сервер. Все это при наличии прав на запись в `cron`, разумеется (который можно править и по FTP).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742734/django-restart-server-or-httpd

Comment: По ссылке там одни КЭПы.

Comment: Cron закрыто.

Answer (score 0):

Если это не продакшен, нагрузка маленькая и mod_python, то можно в настройке хоста apache указать MaxRequestsPerChild 1. Изменения видны будут с каждым новым запросом.

Comment: При этой настройке получается как будто для каждого запроса запускается новый процесс, и получается заново весь код читает и интерпретирует? Если это так то хоть и продакшин (нагрузка очень маленькая), но на время разработки можно менять как вы сказали, допиливать его, и обратно ставить 0 или больше. Я правильно вас понял?

Comment: Разработка должна вестись локально. Чтобы apache считал этот параметр, его нужно перезапустить. Если есть возможность его перезапустить - к чему вообще изначальный вопрос?

Comment: @trec, да правильно.